# Extend Doctrine EntityRepository

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I have written a class BasicRepository in order to use it instead of the EntityRepository to add some basic modification like remove all deleted-flaged items.

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Repository;

use AppBundle\DataFixtures\ORM\LoadEventPrioData;
use AppBundle\Entity\Location;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class BasicRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function createQueryBuilder($alias, $indexBy = null)
    {
        $query = parent::createQueryBuilder($alias);

        dump(parent::getClassName());
        dump($this->getClassName());

        if (property_exists($this->getClassName(), 'isDeleted')) {
            dump("Ping");
            $query->andWhere($alias.'.isDeleted = :false')->setParameter('false', false);
        }
        else {
            dump("Pong");
        }
        return $query;
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
...
public function searchAction(Request $request) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $meta = new ClassMetadata('AppBundle:Location');
        $er = new BasicRepository($em, $meta);
        $query = $er->createQueryBuilder('u');

        ...
```

My aim is that - if the property "isDeleted" (boolean) exists in the Entity - the Query should contain an additional Where-Statement.

For some strange reason property_exists always return false - even when the property exits in the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get your idea. The correct place you're looking for is Doctrine Filters. Check this package: https://github.com/DeprecatedPackages/DoctrineFilters#usage

There you can find example exactly with your use case:

```
<?php

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadata;
use Symplify\DoctrineFilters\Contract\Filter\FilterInterface;

final class SoftdeletableFilter implements FilterInterface
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function addFilterConstraint(ClassMetadata $entity, $alias)
    {
        if ($entity->getReflectionClass()->hasProperty('isDeleted')) {
            return "$alias.isDeleted = 0";
        }

        return '';
    }

}
```